# Prevent user access from specific heroku addons

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I am looking for a way to prevent user access the specific addons.
I want to give him accesss to other addons like mezmo or heroku connect but not to specific addons like heroku postgres.
Heroku user management only allows either access to all addons or to none.
Is there anything that I can do to solve this? Like any specific addons that will password protect the postgres addons or something?